# Setting Responsive Background Image of Website (Full Width and Height)

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, responsiveness

I'm having a website with a background image which fills the entire background via pure css (`background-image`etc properties). The image is an image with heaps of text inside, so I've chosen the PNG format, and the min file size I can achieve for the 2500 px width version is 1.4MB. All the other size versions are below 1 MB. The width sizes I have stored for responsiveness are:

2500px, 2000px, 1500px, 1000px, 750px, 500px

My question is; what's the best way to code the responsiveness of them? I've read some posts, and the usual `min-width` media query would download a new image on every resize event which crosses a breakpoint, which is probably not optimal. I came across `min-device-width`, to do sth like:

```
#background {
  background-image: url(500px_version.png);
}

@media (min-device-width:500px) {
  
  #background {
    background-image: url(750px_version.png);
  }

}

@media (min-device-width:750px) {
  
  #background {
    background-image: url(1000px_version.png);
  }

}

@media (min-device-width:1000px) {
  
  #background {
    background-image: url(1500px_version.png);
  }

}
```

With the advantage that this will not be tied to the viewport but the device itself. If you for example scale down a browser window of a large laptop, it will not redownload the image when crossing breakpoints, which thus avoids unnecessary downloads.

Interestingly, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width) comments this feature to be deprecated, and [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=min-device-width) doesn't even find it. Is it thus not the preferable way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution

Comment: Yeah most likely not, the particular "danger" I see is when users switch from portrait to landscape modes and vice-versa. I've never visited a website which reloads background images when doing so, you see what I mean? And your link doesn't seem to be cross-browser compatible :/